# Calling child class from parent class in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, react-native

I'm new to react and decided to try my hands on basic react programming.
I wrote my own class and added it to the react-native root file-App.js. When I try to compile and run the code it throws an error on the android expo app that allows me to view my changes. The code is as shown

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

class welcome extends React.Component {
   render() {
   return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Master</Text>
     </View>
  );
 }
}

export default class App extends React.Component {
   render() {
   return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text>Welcome</Text>
       <welcome />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
   },
});
```

Please what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: i noticed you didn't export your welcome class. What is your error so we can help you.

Comment: Thank you. With your help I was able to rectify the issue. For some weird reason I don't know the welcome class had to start with a capital so "welcome" had to become "Welcome"